# When does a nib height get set?

Tags: ios, swift, nib

I have a custom UITableViewCell which I'm trying to setup in a nib for my tableview. I have a method that is used to setup my cell, `setupCell()` that doesn't seem to be getting my height correctly.

I set the height in the tableView heightForRow method like so:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(kProfilePicIdentifier) as! ProfilePictureTableViewCell
    return cell.computeHeight()
}
```

This takes the cell to this method to set the height:

```
override func computeHeight() -> CGFloat {
    let screenRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let height = screenRect.height * 0.4

    return height
}
```

The setupCell method looks like so:

```
override func setupCell() {
    profilePicture.image = UIImage(named: "prof_pic")
    profilePicture.layer.cornerRadius = profilePicture.frame.size.height / 4.6
    profilePicture.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

The cornerRadius formula is what gets it working for exactly the height I set. But, as soon as I change the height of the `computeHeight` function, which in turn changes the tableViewCell row height, the circle gets messed up because it doesn't seem to be getting the correct height.

The profilePicture outlet is set to be half the size of the total height of the view, but it doesn't seem to reflect that when I call `setupCell`, it always gets set to a constant size instead of half the size of the view.

Does anyone know when the height of the cell is actually set? And when could I call this method so that I could easily just divide the height by 2 to get the radius?

Edit: So I got away with making it work by putting the corner logic in `layoutSubviews()`, however I'm still interested to know when the actual heights of the images inside the nib get set.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using auto layout, you can override viewDidLayoutSubviews which will be called immediately after a pass of the layout engine. viewDidlayoutSubviews can be called multiple times. By the time the last time viewDidLayoutSubviews is called all of viewController's subviews frames are set. However, when a specific frame is set is undefined, but you can put a print statement in viewDidLayoutSubviews to get a sense of which pass set it's frame.